# Tracking Email and SMS metrics with a custom field

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, data-export, sendsmsactivity

My company sends order confirmation emails that each include an order number along with other transactional comms that also use this same order number.  I need to be able to export the sent/bounced data including the email name + order number for all emails we send hat include an order number.
The emails are triggered in real time from a JSON payload coming in which I use SSJS to parse into AMPScript variables and then print the variables in the email template.
Any suggestions on how I might be able to get this one attribute/variable from each individual email plus the email name across 10 different emails into an exportable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a Send Log solution for capturing few standard fields + any custom fields you choose to add.

Here are description on how to configure sendlogs for [SMS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387998&type=1) an [Email](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386631&type=1).